# Find out the specific row that was selected in Dash DataTable

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a Dash DataTable with `row_selectable` set to `"multi"`. Therefore, the user can select multiple rows via a checkbox that will appear next to each row of the DataTable.

I also have a callback that has as input `Input("datatable-id", "selected_rows")`. Therefore, each time the user selects a row, I get ALL the rows that are selected.

What I want to do is to update my database column is_selected based on the row that the user just selected. To get the row that the user just selected I can either:

1. Read my entire is_selected column of my database and find the difference between that and selected_rows.
2. Use selected_rows to update ALL the rows in my database.

I wonder, is there another better way to find out which specific row the user selected? So that I can simply update my single row in my database accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can use a `dcc.Store` as a way to get access to the previous state.
If I'm not wrong, your problem is a comparison between two states: the state_0, the one before the interaction; and the state_1, the one after the interaction.

In that case, using only DashTable attributes, it is hard (at least I don't know how) to get the previous state of selected rows. With that in mind you can create a `dcc.Store` to store the last state of selected_rows to get access every time the callback is triggered. In other words, put the `data` as the `Output` off the callback and a `State` to get the access to state_0. Update the data with the current selected_rows after making a simple set difference between the current selected_rows and the previous one.